# Calcular tiempo transcurrido de una fecha a la fecha actual laravel 5.7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, carbon

Estoy intentando calcular el tiempo transcurrido de una fecha a la fecha actual al no ser posible usar Carbon en la versión de laravel 5.7 lo consigo de la siguiente manera

**Controller**

```
$consulta = Consulta::find($id);

        $fecha_actual = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $fecha1 = new DateTime($consulta->created_at);
        $fecha2 = new DateTime($fecha_actual);
        $tiempo_transcurrido = $fecha1->diff($fecha2);
```

**Vista**

```
{{ $consulta->id }}

{{ $consulta->id_secondary }}

{{ $consulta->itx }}

{{ $tiempo_transcurrido }}
```

Hasta aquí me funciona correctamente el problema me viene cuando necesito hacer lo mismo con una consulta Get como el ejemplo siguiente

**Controller**

```
$consulta = Consulta::where('id_secondary', $id)->get();
```

**Vista**

```
@foreach($consulta as consul)

 {{ $consul->id }}

 {{ $consul->id_secondary }}

 {{ $consul->itx }}

 {{ $consul->created_at }} <-- aqui es donde necesito mostrar el tiempo transcurrido desde la fecha que contiene el campo $consul->created_at -->

@endforeach
```

Alguien seria tan amable de orientarme como lo puedo conseguir ?

Comment: Claro que puedes usar Carbon, de hecho YA viene incluido en Laravel.

Comment: lo acabo de probar pero me da error  htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given  si borro esto ->diff(now()) me funciona correctamente pero al añadirlo me da el error

Comment: me da el error DateTime::diff() expects at least 1 parameter, 0 given

Comment: Podrías revisar si created_at es una instancia de carbon

Comment: no entiendo como comprobar eso

Comment: Created_at es un campo de la tabla a la que llamo con la consulta "consulta que muestro en la pregunta", dicho campo se genera de forma automatica al insertar el registro. "No se si esto responde a tu pregunta"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Carbon 1.x viene incluido por defecto en Laravel 5.7, de hecho las fechas de los modelos ya son instancias de Carbon, por lo cual puedes hacer:

En la vista (blade) sería algo así, para ver la diferencia en segundos:

```
@foreach($consulta as $consul)

    Tiempo transcurrido: {{ $consul->created_at->diffInSeconds(now()) }}

@endforeach
```

Si ya conoces Carbon, sabes que puedes usar `diffForHumans()` y utilizar la localización respectiva para español.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien como hacerlo uso el foreach en el controlador ?  y como lo muestro en la vista? ya que en el foreach de la vista necesito mostrar el tiempo transcurrido calculado a partir de la fecha del campo created_at pero también necesito mostrar el resto de campos de la consulta

Comment: Entonces falta información en la pregunta, agrega el código de la vista, finalmente nosotros ayudamos con lo que vemos.

Comment: @jorge revisa la edición que hice, utilizando otro método para que te muestre la diferencia en segundos.

Comment: Funciona correctamente muchas gracias por su tiempo y ayuda